# Max Number of callouts in future

Tags: rest-api, future

Would like to clarify quick point as below statement in [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_callouts_timeouts.htm) is causing confusion.

```
A single Apex transaction can make a maximum of 100 callouts to an HTTP request or an API call.
```

So suppose a trigger(running in bulk context) is calling a future method which in turn is invoking a http REST based API call. Would this 100 call out limits apply or not(as callout is in asynchronous context)

In other words, We have to update 10,000 records in near future. we know trigger executes 200 records at a time. Our rest service can't take more than one record at a time. Will apex callouts be made for all 200 records one by one ?  What will happen APEX callouts for other records getting updated?

We're trying to avoid making such huge number of call outs together but keen to know the behaviour, if at all this happens

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Would this 100 call out limits apply or not(as callout is in asynchronous context)

No, it will not apply as each future call from trigger will be a separate transaction. Again if your single future call is doing a 100 http callout, then the limit applies here.

> Will apex callouts be made for all 200 records one by one ?

This depends on how you are playing with trigger.new because future method will be separate transaction once invoked from trigger, If you are invoking a future method for each trigger.new instance and doing a http callout intern from future, then yes. Again make sure when u r invoking future method from a synchronous transaction has a limit of maximum 100 future call per synchronous transaction.

Comment: thanks!  this is what I also think but wanted to confirm